# Django Conditional Expressions to display different text strings based on Foreignkey value

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, conditional-operator

I am trying to get a product description to automatically format based on the fields in the database record.

I have looked at the Case() method but not sure if I can use it?

The function is not working and only displays the value in the elif at the end, which I have given "not working" as a test.

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

class FilmSpecs(models.Model):
    NO_UP = (
        (1,'1 Up'),
        (2,'2 Up'),
        (4,'4 Up'),
        (6,'6 Up'),
        (8,'8 Up'),
    )
    TINTS = (
        ('NAT', 'Natural'),
        ('TNT', 'Tinted'),
        ('OPQ', 'Opaque'), 
             )
    SLIPLEVEL = (
        ('STD', 'Standard'),
        ('LOW', 'Low Slip'),
        ('HIGH', 'High Slip'),
    )
    
    stock_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Stock Code", unique=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="Film Description")
    label_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Label Description")
    film_type = models.ForeignKey('settings.FilmType', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank = False, related_name='film_type', verbose_name="Film Type")
    sale_type = models.ForeignKey('settings.SaleType', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank = False, related_name='sale_type', verbose_name="Sale Type")
    film_width = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False, verbose_name="Film Width (mm)")
    guss_closed_width = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=False, default=0, verbose_name="Gussetted Closed Width (mm)")
    micron = models.FloatField(null=False,blank=False, default=0,verbose_name="Micron")
    slip_level = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=SLIPLEVEL, null=True)
    roll_weight = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Roll Weight (kg)")
    strip_out_size = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Strip Out Size (mm)")
    edge_trim_size = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name = "Edge Trim (mm)")
    tint = models.CharField(choices=TINTS, max_length=200, default="NAT", null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Film Tint")
    treatment = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, verbose_name="Film Treated")
    product_notes = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, verbose_name="Product Notes", blank=True)
    strip_out = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Strip Out Size (mm)")
    run_no_up = models.IntegerField(choices=NO_UP, verbose_name="No Up")
    
    def film_description(self):
        if self.film_type == "Layflat Tubing":
            film_description = "{}mm x {}mu {} {} ".format(self.film_width, self.micron, self.tint, self.film_type)
        elif self.film_type == "Centrefold Sheeting":
            film_description = "{}mm / {}mu x {} {} {}".format(self.film_width, int(self.film_width) * 2, self.micron, self.tint, self.film_type)
        elif self.film_type == "Single Wound Sheeting":
            film_description = "{}mm x {} {} {}".format(self.film_width, self.micron, self.tint, self.film_type)
        elif self.film_type == "Double Wound Sheeting":
            film_description = "{}mm x {} {} {}".format(self.film_width, self.micron, self.tint, self.film_type)
        else:
            film_description = "{}mm / {}mm * {} {} {}".format(self.film_width, int(self.film_width) * 2, self.micron, self.tint, "Not Working")
        return film_description
```

Comment: `self.film_type` is the foreign key, so you need the field. For example, if the field is `name`, `self.film_type.name == "Layflat Tubing"`